# How to increase the number of recent launches in the menu of JUnit view in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit

How can I increase the number of recent launches in Eclipse's recent launches menu in JUnit view? I need to display more than 10, because I am running tests on many projects at once using CDT's "Launch groups" feature, and currently there are more than 10 projects. I know I can go to the "History" menu, but I'd prefer to see the results in the menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the icon instead of the down arrow.

[image]

You will get a window with a input field. Change the count as required.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not affect menu length.